# jquery div appendTo

Tags: jquery, html, appendto

I have generated like this:
html

```
 <button type="submit" class="button" id="addk">Add div</button>
 <div class="body" style="float: left;">
```

and

javascript

```
var RL;
RL = 0;
$("#addk").click(function () {
       RL = RL + 1;
        RN = "Tekst" + RL;
         $("<div id='" + RN + "' class='we' > " +
          "<B>Kon" + RL +"</B>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button'  onclick='Add(" + RN + ");' >AddNext</button>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button'  onclick='Close(" + RN + ");' >Close</button>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button' onclick='Up(" + RN + ");' >Up</button>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button' onclick='Down(" + RN + ");' >Down</button><br />" +
           "<br />"  + "<input type='text'>" + "<br /><br />" + '</div>').

         appendTo(".body");
    });
function Close (){
 $(".we").hide();// doesn't work
}
function Up (){
  if ($(this).hasClass('.we')) {
        $(this).closest('.body').insertBefore($(this).closest('.body').prev());
    }
}
function Up (we){
 if ($(this).hasClass('.we')) {
        $(this).closest('.body').insertBefore($(this).closest('.body').prev());
    }
}
```

I do not know how to take a div id and do operations on functions, ie start up / down and close.

I can not add a picture but it's about

```
<div id="Text2" class="we">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WmbmF/24/

Comment: no need in dot in class name here : `hasClass('.we')`

Answer (score 0):

Since the submit button are added dynamically, you need to use event delegation to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

You can try to give the button some specific ID for the Add/Close/Up/Down functions.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WmbmF/26/)
(*Show only the close function, try adding multiple divs and closing them.*)

Comment: Ok. It works and understand. But as it is now run functions up / down?